# How to get available dates for reservation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to build a system which lets users reserve a place, let's say a homestay.

My table looks like this:

```
table: homestay
columns: id

table: reserve
columns: id, homestay_id, datein, dateout

table: homestaybooking_inventory:
columns: id, homestay_id, reserve_id
```

My function looks like this:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
    $datein = $_POST['start'];
    $dateout = $_POST['end'];

    if (isset ($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $query="SELECT id FROM reservation BETWEEN datein >= $datein AND dateout <= $dateout";
        $q=mysql_fetch_array($query);
        if (mysql_num_rows()<1)
        {
         echo "not available. please pick another dates";
        } 
        else
        {
             echo "available. Please Next for make a reservation.";
        }
    }
```

I have an interface where it has a `datein` picker and `dateout` picker. User will pick between two dates. Then, they will click the "Check availability" button. And it would display whether the is homestay available or not at that date. If not available, the user will pick again. If available, the user can go to the next step. There is reservation form.

Comment: select id, date1, date2, etc... from mytable, etc...

Comment: @MarcoMura pardon. can you explain more. when a user click for availablity button it will display the date is available or not.

Comment: Create a query that will obtain the data, then, populate html, then, when a user click on something you can show those data.

Comment: @MiRa could *you* explain a bit more? Your question is limited in info - what have you tried, what happened?

Comment: So wich is your problem?

Comment: @ericpap the code cannot functioning very well as i want. any idea to solve my problem?

Comment: Well "my code not function very well" it's not a good description of the problem you are having. If a user choose 01/12/2014 to 05/12/2014 and you have avaiability only on 3 and 4 dec, what do you want to do?

Comment: Like Jerry Jerry Maguire says: help me help you!

Comment: @ericpap whats your problem now? im cannot understand. my question is when user click the "Check availability" button it would display whether the is homestay available or not at that date.

Comment: Well "my code not function very well" it's not a good description of the problem you are having. If a user choose 01/12/2014 to 05/12/2014 and you have avaiability only on 3 and 4 dec, what do you want to do? 

my answer : user have to pick another date.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. You are asking the user for two dates: in and out date. That means that to have avaiability, you need to have de room or whatever free on every day in the range. So what happend if you only have the room free for two of the three days the user choose?

Comment: @ericpap user have to pick another date again.

Comment: oh.. i see. Your question was unclear. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Shouln't this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows()<1)
```

be replace by this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows()>0)
```

Comment: you are querying the table reservations. If i'm not wrong if you find any records between those days, the room is not avaible. So if you find any records (num_rows>0) the room is not avaible. I'm i worng?

Comment: Without knowing the actual problem they're encountering, all I can say is that your logic is sound.

Comment: Well i don't understand the downvote then. Hope it helps the person who make the question.

Comment: The downvote is there because I can't remove it unless the answer is edited.